# Android gradle idea absent test R file

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a project which uses some resource files for testing. Now I try to migrate to gradle. The problem is : R file from the test project is unavailable. I try to build tests from IDEA, not from android studio. So when I try to import R file from test project, compilation error occurs

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven {url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/jayway/'}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    instrumentTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.0.1'
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        testPackageName "com.oso.ono.tests"
    }

    sourceSets{
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        instrumentTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the Gradle tests from command line?

Comment: Yes it works, but I don't know how to use R file from test project. IDEA does not generate it and when I try to use it it highlight it with compilation error. Actually tests work without resources and AndroidManifest file

Comment: I added test_strings.xml to my project and work with it buit it is wrong, because it will built to the release project and I will have to remove it manually.

Answer (score 0):

correct yours sourceSet.

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src','gen']
            resources.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
```